# Not sure how to rearrange this formula.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation in the form,
$$
z = k_1 \cdot \frac{k_2 xy}{\left(x^2 - y^2\right)^2}
$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constant. I need to rewrite it in terms of $y$ but the closest I've come is an equation in the form,
$$
x^4 - xy\left(2xy + \frac{k_1 k_2}{z}\right) + y^4 = 0
$$
but I can't use substitution to solve this. From another approach I get,
$$
\frac{x^2 - y^2}{\sqrt{y}} = \sqrt{\frac{k_1k_2}{z}}
$$
 so I'm rather stuck...

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it is even possible to rewrite the equation in such a way?

Comment: No I don't even know if you can, it's not a question from a textbook if that's what you're asking.

Comment: When one solves for $y$ using computer algebra, you get a horrendously complex solution.

Comment: Oh why is this that some equations cannot be rearranged?

Comment: @JohnMiller That's, in a way, the wrong question to ask. The better question would be "why should all equations be such that they can be rearranged"?

Comment: @5xum I really do not know, perhaps it is only equations that have commutative operations that can be 'easily' rearranged? That was just a guess but you've really got me here.

Comment: Probably a stupid question : is $y$ supposed to be small compared to $x$ ? If this is the case, we could probably generate some approximations.

Comment: That is the general assumption used to make calculations for 'large' magnets at a distance, however in my experiment this does not work as I have used very small and strong magnet. This way I can calculate the theoretical separation of the monopoles, and it'll hopefully coincide with the indirect exchange force.

Answer (score 3):

> $x^4 - 2xy\left(xy + \frac{k_1 k_2}{z}\right) + y^4 = 0$

Rewriting a bit more:
$$\color{blue}{y^4}-2x^2\color{blue}{y^2}-2x\frac{k_1 k_2}{z}\color{blue}{y}+x^4=0$$
This is a [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) in $y$ and in general, that's not easy to solve. Note that the term in $\color{blue}{y^3}$ is missing and that makes it slightly better, you can take a look at [Ferrari's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari's_solution) (see *depressed quartic equation* for the equation without the third degree term) but it will get (very) ugly...

The question is, do you really need (want?) to symbolically solve this for $y$?

Comment: The equation is for a magnet and I'm trying to find $y$ as that is the distance between, if they exist, the monopoles of a magnet.

Comment: If you're not interested in an explicit formula for $y$ (which doesn't really give you a lot of insight anyway, if the formula is _too ugly_), you would typically use software te solve for $y$ with numerical methods.

Comment: Yes I figured that would be easier, was just hoping I wouldn't have to ressort to that as it does not give as much insight as I wanted.

Comment: You can always hope for a pretty solution :-). Now you know that sometimes that's not possible, sometimes it's ugly (too ugly to be useful?) and if you're lucky, you can get a nice explicit formula. I'd say you're in the middle case with this one.

Comment: I've never heard of Ferrari's solution so I'll look into that for a bit, perhaps I'll get some inspiration but for a physical phenomenon it shouldn't be this 'ugly', at least it seems.

Comment: Physical (or other "real life") phenomena often lead to equations with are mathematically _ugly_, at least in the sense that you can't do much analytically or solve explicitly...